# How to access a variable in Adapter class inside the fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a variable **dueAmount** in Adapter Class,

```
var dueAmount: Int = 0
```

and I'm updating this variable inside the onBindViewHolder() method of the adapter class, as:

```
if (transactions[position].youGave) {
            dueAmount += transactions[position].amount.toInt()
    .
    .
}

else {
            dueAmount -= transactions[position].amount.toInt() 
    .
    .
}
```

I'm accessing this variable in Fragment Class like this:

```
if (transactionAdapter.dueAmount > 0) {
    tvAmountDue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), 
    R.color.colorAccent))
    tvAmountDue.text = (transactionAdapter.dueAmount * -1).toString()
} else {
    tvAmountDue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), 
    R.color.colorPrimary))
    tvAmountDue.text = transactionAdapter.dueAmount.toString()
}
```

The value of dueAmount I'm getting in the fragment is always zero (0). However, I've checked its value in Adapter and it is getting updated there but not in Fragment.
I don't know how to properly access this variable in Fragment class.
Please help me resolve this issue

I'm using this inside onResume() of Fragment

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mainActivity.supportActionBar?.title = args.name
        recyclerViewTrnsaction.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        launch {
            context?.let {
                val transactions = getAllTransactions(args.id)
                val transactionAdapter = TransactionAdapter(transactions)
                recyclerViewTrnsaction.adapter = transactionAdapter

                nestedScrollView.post {
                    nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
                }

                if (transactionAdapter.dueAmount > 0) {
                    tvAmountDue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.colorAccent))
                    tvAmountDue.text = (transactionAdapter.dueAmount * -1).toString()
                } else {
                    tvAmountDue.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                    tvAmountDue.text = transactionAdapter.dueAmount.toString()
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you try to use dueAmount variable too early? Could you show more of yours fragment code, please

Comment: @ZSergei I've updated the question, I'm using dueAmount inside onResume(), please check

Comment: Well, I think on the moment when you call `transactionAdapter.dueAmount` `onBindViewHolder` not called yet. What task are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ZSergei  I'm trying to calculate the Balance Due Amount and then display in fragment, is there any way to do that? How do I make sure that 
    onBindViewHolder
is called before
    transactionAdapter.dueAmount

Comment: Maybe you can just calculate balance separately? Create function that takes `transactions` and returns calculated `dueAmount` like this
`fun calculateDueAmount(transactions: List<Transaction>): Int = transactions.sumBy { if (it.youGave) it.amount else -it.amount }`